# Cellpose installation issue

Tags: python, pip

System: MacOS 10.14, python 3.8

I get the following error when I try to pip  install Cellpose

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for opencv-python-headless, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What's your question? With no context, this sounds like a bug, but is there more to the error message you've left out? [We need the full error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). You can [edit]. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: `pip install opencv-python-headless` ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow, next time, please post full error.
Based on my experience, Try

```
pip install Wheel
```

It is a requirement for the package you are trying to install.